# Does the Shopify API have a way to get a list of all installed apps?

Tags: shopify

Does the Shopify API have a way to get a list of all installed apps?

I want to keep a history of all apps installed on my stores. The only relevant thing I can find in the [API docs](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference) is about a Webhook to get notified of an 'app/uninstalled' event.

EDIT

An 'app/installed' event would be ideal, if it existed. It would enhance the security of my stores if I could fetch the list of apps that are installed, or be notified when an app is installed or uninstalled.

To address security concerns, I believe that access to this data should be restricted in the same ways that other API endpoints and webhooks are restricted. The store owner would grant permission to an app to allow it access. This would make it as secure as, for example, customer names.

I'm looking for something roughly equivalent to WordPress's [get_plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins) function, but for Shopify.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use this endpoint to fetch all the installed apps https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/objects/queryroot#connections

##example request##

```
appInstallations (first: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        launchUrl,
        app{
          title
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

No. You cannot use the API to query a shop about what Apps it has installed. Imagine that. You get to know all those little shop details and do what with them? Would be like giving you permission to uninstall Apps too. You see why that is a problem? Bad enough Apps can perform cross-talk with metafields... Apps would be another level of wrong.

Comment: As a store administrator I can see the list of installed apps. I don't see a problem with allowing me read-only access to this same data programmatically.

Comment: In your own store, yes, you can see your Apps. There are tons of things you get in Liquid you don't get with API calls either. So why do want an App that can see your Apps installed when you can just see them in your Admin?

Comment: I would think Shopify would never expose an API endpoint that would reveal what Apps a merchant has installed. That would be like a bank offering up what accounts a customer has, and insurance company what policies a customer has. In other words, no one's business but the merchants.

Comment: I keep my custom themes in git repositories to track changes to them. I want to also track what apps are installed over time. I have automated this for other aspects of a store such pages.json, shop.json .

Comment: With Shopify's permission model, you could limit access to this data to apps that you authorize only. It would be more like a bank providing information about your accounts to an ATM.

Comment: I will go out on limb here and place a bet on the outcome of this ever happening as zero...

Comment: @DavidLazar Can you share any link of it.n your own store, yes, you can see your Apps. There are tons of things you get in Liquid you don't get with API calls either. it would be appreciated. Thanks!